# Issue with writing to NFS Share between Linux and Synology NAS

Tags: 20.04, permissions, mount, nfs

I have NFS share folders I only have read access via Linux, the folders are located my on Synology NAS.

To confirm this I tried to save a file to the NFS folder and I got the pop up saying I don’t have permissions.

Looking at the Synology side (and other posts here) I came up with the following NFS share settings;

Hostname or IP: *
Privilege: Read/Write
Squash: Map all users to admin
Security: sys

Enable asynchronous: Checked
Allow connections from non-privileged ports: checked
Allow users to access mounted subfolders: Checked

I am very inexperienced when it comes to Linux and NFS shares. I should mention I am sunning Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Is there any way to allow write access to my NFS share? Is there any other information I can provide to assist?

Thank you.